# JavaScript Build system using Node.js error in Sublime Text 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, sublimetext2

I'm using Node.js to make a build system in Sublime Text 2 to build JavaScript code. I know how to setup basic build systems in Sublime, but this one is really giving me problems.

JavaScript example code:

```
var end = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < end; i++) {
  console.log("hello world!");  
};
```

1st try:

```
    {
    "cmd": ["node", "$file"]
    }
```

returned this in the console: `[Finished in 0.1s]`

2nd try:

```
{
"cmd": ["node", "$file", "$file_base_name"],
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
"selector": "#.js"
}
```

returns the same thing.

Any help would be much appreciated (I've spend over 2 hours searching google).

EDIT: Fixed `For` to `for` : Same result.

Comment: Could it be a syntax error due to the uppercase F in For?

Comment: Just changed it to `for` from `For` and still same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text 2 you must save your .js file before you build, or the result above will happen.

Simple fix is to save the file (obviously)!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Javascript build system I use on my Mac with Sublime Text. It uses the Webkit engine (SquirrelFish) which comes with OS X, and therefore doesn't require anything special be installed (not even Node.js):

```
{
    "cmd": ["/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

Tips:

1. Use "print(foo)" from within your script to return results to the Sublime console
2. Save your .js file to disk at least once
3. If ".js" files are not automatically selected, ensure you have no other build systems for ".js" in "~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/". Alternately you can manually select the appropriate system from "Tools > Build System"

Hope this helps.