# Node Build System in Sublime Text 2 for the First Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, path, sublimetext2

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582990/javascript-build-system-using-node-js-error-in-sublime-text-2) post on an error with node in Sublime Text 2, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597182/sublime-text-2-making-javascript-build-with-node-js) post on finding where node was installed, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427520/node-js-build-system-in-sublime-text-2) post on what seems to be the same issue, but none of them have helped so far. I would also prefer to use node.js. Please bear in mind, I am a programming newbie, so descriptions of locations of directories will have be absolute path names in order for me to understand.

I followed the instructions [here](http://logicmason.com/2013/adding-a-js-build-system-to-sublime/), and my Node.sublime-build file looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node", "$file", "$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "*.js"
}
```

I restarted Sublime Text 2, but it didn't work. I restarted my computer, but to no avail.
Currently, /usr/local/bin is where node is stored, and my $PATH contains that directory. At least, I think. My $PATH (I am in a bash_profile) looks like this:

```
-bash: /Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/David/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/David/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/David/.rbenv/shims:/Users/David/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

I think the solution may be found in the line in the Sublime Text 2 console error messages that reads,

```
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Do I need to insert /usr/local/bin: into it? If so, how? I am running Mac OS X 10.7.5. Even if there's another thread that I haven't found, I'd gladly forgo reputation points in order to get the solution to my problem.

Cheers!

Comment: I apologize. I forgot to post the error! The file I'm running is called fizzbuzz.js.

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    [cmd:  [u'nodejs', u'/Users/David/dev/HTML/lab/12-20-13/fizzbuzz.js']]
    [dir:  /Users/David/dev/HTML/lab/12-20-13]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]

Comment: You might want to go through [this](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/07/Compiling-Node.js-scripts-in-Windows-7-with-Sublime-Text-3.html) and [this](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/07/Compiling-Cpp-11-Programs-with-Sublime-Text-3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options for getting your build systems to work.

First, you can edit your `Node.sublime-build` file to look like this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file", "$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "*.js"
}
```

by adding `/usr/local/bin/` to the beginning of the `node` command to give its fully qualified path.

---

Alternatively, since you're on Lion (this doesn't work on Mt Lion), you can alter the path for Dock-launched programs (by default it's `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, as you've seen). From Terminal, run the following:

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

(you may have to prefix it with `sudo`, I'm not sure). The, run:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Dock" to quit'
```

and restart Sublime. This has the advantage of allowing other build systems (I'm especially thinking of Ruby, since you're using RVM) to work out of the box, without messing around with their `.sublime-build` files as well. For this and the next option, you'll need to remember to update the path when you update Ruby.

---

The third option, which is necessary on Mountain Lion (not sure about Mavericks) is outlined in my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89076/how-to-set-the-path-osx-applications-use/89077#89077). Basically, you need to edit `/etc/launchd.conf` (or create it if it doesn't exist) to define `PATH`, then save and reboot. This is necessary because the `launchctl` command on 10.8 doesn't do what we want it to do. This option may also work on Lion, but I haven't tested it, since I had already upgraded to Mt Lion before I developed it.

I hope this all helps. Good luck!

Comment: Matt, I followed the instructions at [stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89076/how-to-set-the-path-osx-applications-use/89077#89077), but the only thing that changed was my error message when I build using node: ('[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Users/David/bin:/path/to/gems/bin]').

Comment: @David - what happens if you change the `.sublime-build` file like in option 1? Also, what is the output when you run `which node` at the command line?

Comment: @David - wait a sec, I just reread your error message. It says it's looking for `nodejs`, while your build file says `node`. Are you sure you're building with the correct file?

Comment: I apologize. I hastily replied before I changed the Node.sublime-build file again. Everything is working just fine. As far as updating the path when I update Ruby, will RVM take care of that or I'll just figure out how to cross that bridge when I get to it?

Comment: @David - you'll have to update it yourself, since RVM doesn't know to look there.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please feel free to to click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted. It marks the issue as resolved, and helps any future visitors who may have the same or a similar question. Additionally, we'll both get reputation points for it :)